# TMCbeans doesn't open

Tags: java, oop

I am currently trying to lean java through the famous platform (Mooc.fi).
the course material demands installing other softwares along with TMCbeans.
the problem is that the program does not open after installation.
checked other similar questions, some suggested modifying the path of the file (the TMCconfig in C:\Program Files\TMCBeans\etc )and add the  path of the JDK File. (the problem is that the TMC does not know the jdk file location so some found a solution via including it manually.
the problem is that the "TMCconfig" file can't be accessed for confidential reasons, It can't be modified.
[image: details about the error]

can anyone suggest any other solution please?

REFERENCES: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnjava/comments/u3x1ls/tmcbeans_not_opening_on_mac_and_other_oss/